# What is auxdata in the asm output from solc?

Tags: solidity, compiler

I am using -

```
solc --asm smartcontractname.sol
```

I get at the end of the asm auxdata. I am trying to check different modules to see what is inherited. Does anyone know how auxdata is computed? Here is an example -

> auxdata:
>   0xa165627a7a72305820b41b74dd955b6016ed7df922d97394e291c6cebecd0289470726ff64204a7a790029

I assume this is a hash of the asm or something like that. My purpose is to determine what code specifically is passed into modules.

Comment: I too need an answer to that. I am guessing that it might be some sort of checksum, CRC, etc. But I would like to get a confirmation on that.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer in the section **AUXDATA** of [Diving Into The Ethereum VM Part 5 — The Smart Contract Creation Process](https://medium.com/@hayeah/diving-into-the-ethereum-vm-part-5-the-smart-contract-creation-process-cb7b6133b855) -

> Auxdata is the cryptographic fingerprint of the source code, used for verification. This is just data, and never executed by the EVM.
>
> The gist of it is that auxdata is a hash that you can use to fetch metadata about the deployed contract.

I read Solidity Documentation » Contract Metadata # [Encoding of the Metadata Hash in the Bytecode](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/metadata.html#encoding-of-the-metadata-hash-in-the-bytecode) for detail -

> Because we might support other ways to retrieve the metadata file in the future, the mapping {"bzzr0": } is stored [CBOR](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7049)-encoded. Since the beginning of that encoding is not easy to find, its length is added in a two-byte big-endian encoding. The current version of the Solidity compiler thus adds the following to the end of the deployed bytecode:

```
0xa1 0x65 'b' 'z' 'z' 'r' '0' 0x58 0x20 <32 bytes swarm hash> 0x00 0x29
```

> So in order to retrieve the data, the end of the deployed bytecode can be checked to match that pattern and use the Swarm hash to retrieve the file.